# I murmur without words

Tags: riddle

> I murmur without words.
>   
> I sing without a voice.
>   
> Always marching forward,
>   
> I never have a choice.
>   
> Sometimes I am followed,
>   
> But often I am broken.
>   
> Sometimes I am listened to,
>   
> But words I've never spoken.

What am I?

Comment: Wow, you're churning out lots of excellent short riddles! Keep going :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you are a:

> Heart

I murmur without words.

> Abnormal sounds from the heart are known as heart murmurs

I sing without a voice.

> "Every heart sings a song..." - Plato

Always marching forward,
I never have a choice.

> Hearts keep beating by involuntary action

Sometimes I am followed,
But often I am broken.
Sometimes I am listened to,

> Follow your heart. Broken hearted. Listen to your heart (not your head).

But words I've never spoken.

> ...well, obviously...

Answer (score 5):

Could you be

> Rain

I murmur without words.

> Falling rain seems like a murmuring crowd

I sing without a voice.

> [Rainsticks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainstick) are a common musical instrument

Always marching forward,
I never have a choice.

> Rain can only fall, never going upwards

Sometimes I am followed,

> By a thunder

But often I am broken.

> By umbrellas?

Sometimes I am listened to,

> Have you ever been in your bed listening to falling rain?

But words I've never spoken.

Answer (score 4):

I'm thinking the:

> Wind
>
> A small breeze , wind-chimes, it's not like the wind ever blows backwards or chooses where it goes. You can follow the winds or listen to them to try and predict the weather(sailing) , and you can find shelter or clothes to break the wind. *(I'm not 100% happy with the answer but it's all I can think of)*

Comment: Sorry, not the answer, but it's a good thought.  I'd say "always marching forward" wouldn't fit, as sometimes the wind doesn't blow.  Also, I'm not sure how the wind can be "broken".

Comment: Oh wait, duh... windbreaker.  Still, keep trying!

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps the answer is along these lines:

> A babbling brook, murmuring, singing unable to stop or retreat.
>   It is possible to follow the course of a stream; and white water is broken by rocks and shallows. Certainly it is possible to listen to it and even to find answers; but no words are spoken.

Comment: It's a good answer, but I can't say I've ever heard a river/brook sing.

Answer (score 3):

My answer:

> A train engine

I murmur without words.

> Purr of the engine

I sing without a voice.

> Mobil makes your engine sing

Always marching forward,
I never have a choice.

> Trains can't go backwards

Sometimes I am followed,

> by other cars or trains

But often I am broken.

> engines are notorious for breaking

Sometimes I am listened to,
But words I've never spoken.

> A conductor would be listening to the engine